# Got confusing code this.\u002Ector() in our companies old c# project. What does it mean?

Tags: c#

I have got a confusing function  `this.\u002Ector()` within the constructor of my company's old project. What does it mean?

```
 public Common(ref string a_strUserContext)
    {
    bool a_blnQuietMode = false;
    bool a_blnUseSessionToStoreGUID = false;
  // ISSUE: explicit constructor call
    this.\u002Ector(ref a_strUserContext, ref a_blnQuietMode, ref 
   a_blnUseSessionToStoreGUID);
  }
```

Comment: It means the same thing as `this(ref a_strUserContext, ref a_blnQuietMode, ref a_blnUseSessionToStoreGUID);`

Comment: It means that the source code you work with was not written by a programmer but decompiled from an executable file.  Talk to your supervisor about it.

Comment: FWIW I just came about this when decompiling some C# code using dotPeek, this may be of interest to someone, maybe the old code was decompiled at some point?

Answer (score 2):

It is a call to a constructor using IL-like syntax. `u\002E` is Unicode for `.` and combined with `this` and `ctor`, you have a call to a constructor in the same class.

Answer (score 1):

I had an experiment for reverse eng. the `.DLL` and i found out this code is generated by the tool while de-compiling. And this code means nothing at all if removed.

You will need to make sure correct part is removed. Tool(decompiler) i was using JetBrain's [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

Code Sample with and without

```
  public class Engine : BaseEntity
  {
    public string EngineValue { get; set; }

    public Engine()
    {
      base.\u002Ector();
    }
  }

  public class Engine : BaseEntity
  {
    public string EngineValue { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain where this tool is? When I decompile I get base.\u002Ector(); instead of the working method.

Answer (score 0):

002E = **.**   [Unicode for a full stop]

ctor = Constructor [Short form]

Also a shortcut for creating a default constructor by typing ctor and pressing TAB two times [*tested in visual studio*].

*this.ctor* is here somehow changed into *this.\u002Ector* in your code. Might have been a unintentional result of an incorrect encoding process.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually:

```
public Common(ref string a_strUserContext)
{
  bool a_blnQuietMode = false;
  bool a_blnUseSessionToStoreGUID = false;

  this.ctor(ref a_strUserContext, ref a_blnQuietMode, ref 
  a_blnUseSessionToStoreGUID);
}
```

002E is a full stop or simply a full stop ('.')